# Declaring instances of parameterized type synonyms

Tags: haskell, types

I have a bunch of functions that work on Vectors, i.e. lists with type-enforced lengths.

I'm trying to make my types easier to write, i.e. instead of writing

```
foo :: (Fold Integer v, Map Integer Integer v v, ...) => ...
```

I'm declaring a new class `NList` so I can just write `foo :: NList v Integer => ...`

The (simplified) class looks like this:

```
class ( Fold (v i) i
      , Map i i (v i) (v i)
      , Map i (Maybe i) (v i) (v (Maybe i))
      ) => NList v i
```

As you can see, I have to keep the "vector" type separate from the "item" type (i.e. `v` separate from `i`) so that I can do things like `Map` onto a `Maybe` vector.

As such, `v` must have kind `* -> *`, and `i` kind `*`.

However, when I try to instantiate it with vectors like so:

```
instance NList Vec2 Integer
instance NList Vec3 Integer
...
```

I get the following error:

```
Type synonym `Vec2' should have 1 argument, but has been given none
In the instance declaration for `NList Vec2 Integer'
```

Now, I'm very new to type-level programming, and I understand that I'm likely doing this in a very backward fashion. Is it possible to instantiate a type synonym like this? Do any type-wizards have suggestions for better ways to accomplish my goals?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem here is that `Vec2` and `Vec3` are presumably declared as something like this:

```
type Vec2 a = Vec (S (S Z)) a
type Vec3 a = Vec (S (S (S Z))) a
```

Type synonyms cannot be partially-applied, for various arcane reasons (they would lead to type-level lambdas, which wreck havoc with all sorts of things related to instance resolution and inference — imagine if you could define `type Id a = a` and make it an instance of `Monad`).

That is to say, you can't make `Vec2` an instance of anything, because you can't use `Vec2` as if it was a fully-fledge type constructor with the kind `* -> *`; it's effectively a type-level "macro" that can only be fully applied.

However, you *can* define type synonyms as partial applications themselves:

```
type Vec2 = Vec (S (S Z))
type Vec3 = Vec (S (S (S Z)))
```

These are equivalent, except that your instances will be permitted.

If your `Vec3` type actually looks like

```
type Vec3 a = Cons a (Cons a (Cons a Nil)))
```

or similar, then you're out of luck; you'll have to use a `newtype` wrapper if you want to give any instances. (On the other hand, you should be able to avoid defining instances directly on these types entirely by giving instances for `Nil` and `Cons` instead, allowing you to use `Vec3` as an instance.)

Note that with GHC 7.4's new [constraint kinds](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127), you can avoid a separate type entirely, and simply define a *constraint synonym:*

```
type NList v i =
    ( Fold (v i) i
    , Map i i (v i) (v i)
    , Map i (Maybe i) (v i) (v (Maybe i))
    )
```

As far as your approach in general goes, it should basically work fine; the same general idea is used by the [Vec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Vec) package. The huge number of classes and large contexts can make error messages very confusing and slow down compilation, but such is the nature of type-level hackery. However, if you have a base `Vec` type defined as the usual GADT:

```
data Vec n a where
    Nil :: Vec Z a
    Succ :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a
```

then you don't actually need any typeclasses at all. If it's defined in some other manner but is still parametrised on a type-level natural, then you can replace all the classes with one:

```
data Proxy s = Proxy

class Nat n where
    natElim
        :: ((n ~ Z) => r)
        -> (forall m. (n ~ S m, Nat m) => Proxy m -> r)
        -> Proxy n
        -> r
```

This should allow you to eliminate the contexts altogether, but makes defining the operations on the vectors a bit trickier.

Comment: Very cool, thanks. The one thing I don't get is the last example. What's up with the tilda operator?

Comment: It's an [equality constraint](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/equality-constraints.html). If you have a `Num a` constraint in scope, you can use arithmetic operators on values of type `a`; if you have an `(a ~ b)` constraint in scope, you can use `a` values as `b` values and vice versa. Basically, you can read `(n ~ Z) => r` as "prove to me that `n` is `Z`, and I'll give you an `r`".