# Instancing tuples

Tags: haskell, type-synonyms

I have a class, `C`, of `* -> *` types.

```
class C f where
  foo :: f a -> a -> a
```

I also have two types, `A` and `B`, which are instances of `C`

```
instance C A where
  foo a x = ...

instance C B where
  foo b x = ...
```

For various reasons, I also want the type `D`, defined as follows, to be an instance of `C`.

```
type D x = (A x, B x)
```

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289893/declaring-instances-of-parameterized-type-synonyms), type synonyms can't be partially applied, and to define the instance as I would like, I either need to define it in steps (preferable) or define `D` as a newtype (less preferable). It seems to me like there should be some way to accomplish the former, but I haven't been able to figure one out so far. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I would advise not to call a construct like that _dual_. The word is quite universally used in [the category theory sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_object) in Haskell. (Though thinking about it, we already have similar name clashes, e.g. [map](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:map) vs [Map](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#t:Map), and it seems no big problem.)

Comment: As for the question, I don't think there is a good solution. [GHC _can_ in fact](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#type-synonyms) apply type synonyms partially under certain circumstances, but in this case that won't work because `(,)` works fundamentally as a type-function of two _unrelated_ arguments. You _must_ introduce an actual variable like `x` to couple them. A `newtype` or rather `data` will be the way to go. Or just use [`Product`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Data-Functor-Product.html).

Comment: @leftaroundabout yes, I was aware of the clash, and that isn't the name that I'm using in my program. I just couldn't come up with a better one for the question at the time of writing.

Comment: @leftaroundabout If you move your comment into a question, I will accept it.